# Java Swing Hebrew font scaling problem with high dpi screen scaling

Tags: java, swing, scaling, nimbus

Some Hebrew (Ivrit) characters take two unicode characters to display. This is fine at 100% scaling of my Java Swing Application. But at higher resolution (can be choosen in Windows 10 for example) the characters are seperated into two.
This is the code:

```
DataButton jButton = new DataButton(
        "<html><span>" + unicode + "</span></html>", unicode);
```

I had to use the html tags in order to make it display correctly at all.

What can I do about this problem? (I am using Nimbus and openJava 14)

[image: Ivrit Keyboards]

Comment: What are the hex values of the characters? I can't investigate without knowing the characters. Also, you may want to file a bug with Oracle.

Comment: "\u05D1\u05BC" "\u05DB\u05BC" "\u05E4\u05BC"

Comment: I would file a bug report with Oracle about this.

Answer (score 1):

If it can not be done in Swing, use JavaFX in Swing. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

Comment: This is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make images from the letters and display them as icons on the buttons.

Comment: There is one problem with this solution. The icons become coarse with high dpi scaling.

Comment: You may want to make the images at high resolution and have the buttons scale them down.